# Twilio replying messages with 51465

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We have twilio's paid account, using rest api when we are sending messages to Indian mobile number's from twilio's **US** number in some phone's we are receiving with twilio's number but in some phone's we are getting with **51465**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I recommend checking out the [Twilio SMS guidelines for India](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/in). We also have a page on [limitations on sending SMS to Indian mobile devices](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices).

The key point in these resources is:

> **The sender IDs are changed to the format “XX-NNNNNN”**
>
> The sender IDs are altered before SMS messages are delivered to end
>   users. End users are very likely to see a sender ID composed of 2
>   letters followed by 6 numbers instead of the Sender ID you specified.
>   Due to the sender ID change, SMS recipients are unable to send a reply
>   back to your Twilio phone number.

India does not support two way messaging because it changes the sender ID. We cannot control that right now.